# My Hero Image is not centered on Mobile

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to create a full container image that is centered nicely on all screens.

```
<body>

<!-- Preloader -->
<div class="page-loader">
    <div class="loader">Loading...</div>
</div>

<!-- Navigation start -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-transparent navbar-fixed-top">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#custom-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                <img src="assets/images/kerriwalshjenningswhite.png"  alt="Kerri Walsh">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="custom-collapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="https://www.kerriwalshjennings.co">Home</a>
                </li>

                        <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="http://www.kerriwalshjennings.co/pages/gallery.html" target="_blank">Gallery</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="http://www.kerriwalshjennings.co/pages/sponsors.html" target="_blank">Sponsors</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="http://www.kerriwalshjennings.co/pages/bio.html" target="_blank">Bio</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="http://www.kerriwalshjennings.co/pages/contact.html" target="_blank">Contact</a>
                    </li>

        </div>

    </div>

</nav>
<!-- Navigation end -->

<!-- Home start -->
<section id="home" class="home-section home-parallax home-fade kenburns home-full-height">

    <div class="hero-slider">
        <ul class="slides">

            <li class="bg-light-30">
                <div class="img">
                    <img src="assets/images/kerribig4.jpg" />
                </div>

                <div class="hs-caption">
                    <div class="caption-content">
                        <p class="hs-title-size-1 font-serif mb-30">
                            Hello & welcome
                        </p>
                        <h1 class="hs-title-size-5 font-alt mb-40">
                            I am Kerri Walsh
                        </h1>
                        <a href="#about" class="section-scroll btn btn-border-w btn-circle">Learn More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li class="bg-light">
                <div class="img">
                    <img src="assets/images/kerribig3.jpg" />
                </div>

                <div class="hs-caption">
                    <div class="caption-content">
                        <p class="hs-title-size-1 font-serif mb-30">
                            I am
                        </p>
                        <h1 class="hs-title-size-5 font-alt mb-40">
                            A Mother
                        </h1>
                        <a href="#about" class="section-scroll btn btn-border-w btn-circle">Learn More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li class="bg-light">
                <div class="img">
                    <img src="assets/images/kerribig2.jpg" />
                </div>

                <div class="hs-caption">
                    <div class="caption-content">
                        <p class="hs-title-size-1 font-serif mb-30">
                            I am
                        </p>
                        <h1 class="hs-title-size-5 font-alt mb-40">
                            An Olympian
                        </h1>
                        <a href="#about" class="section-scroll btn btn-border-w btn-circle">Learn More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>

</section >
<!-- Home end -->
```

And then here is the first part of my style.css. I need to make this image appear a in the center of the screen on mobile so you can actually see Kerri Walsh

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
}

body {
    background: #fff;
    font: 400 13px/1.8 "Lato", sans-serif;
    color: #666;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

img {
    /*width: 100%; */
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: The website is: www.kerriwalshjennings.co !

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to be a background image, which I think you want. 
Then you can use this method:

```
.home-section {
  /* Location of the image */
  background-image: url(images/background-photo.jpg);

  /* Background image is centered vertically and horizontally at all times */
  background-position: center center;

  /* Background image doesn't tile */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  /* Background image is fixed in the viewport so that it doesn't move when 
     the content's height is greater than the image's height */
  background-attachment: fixed;

  /* This is what makes the background image rescale based
     on the container's size */
  background-size: cover;

  /* Set a background color that will be displayed
     while the background image is loading */
  background-color: #464646;
}
```

It's responsive and will look good on all screens. And yes, you can ofcourse change the background images using jQuery or native JavaScript just like you've done with the images.

Best regards,

Comment: @SteveO'Dell updated the code, add it to .home-section and it works.